# How to view Progress image in between saving the records when clicks on save button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

when i had given name in inputtext then i click save button,i need to show progress image when the record saved the progress image should be closed and success message need to show(user had saved).I had used actionStatus.

    
        
            
            
                
                    
                        **Please Wait**

could anybody help me..............

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your actionstatus in following manner. it will display image for you.

```
<apex:actionStatus id="updatestatus" >
            <apex:facet name="start" >
              <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
            </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Put this code where you want to show your image. You can put that near to your save button

Comment: Thanks for your answer Himanshu..I am using javascript for validation for name to mandatory(name field is required).that validations are not working....

Comment: is it happening after updating this code ?

Comment: yes its working,but validations are not working.when i give empty name and clicks,the record is saving but validation is not working and progress image is working.

Comment: was validation working before ?

Comment: name must be required.when name fill then after this progress image should come,when save button clicks.

Comment: actionstatus run everytime you make a call to server so you have two option here.

1. Move your validation controller side and throw an error from there.
2. write a js function at visualforce side and call that function from your command button and from this js function call a apex:actionfunction after validating your name field.

it is not possible to give complete answer in comment section so If you are not clear with answer I would suggest you to open another question with your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30779/discussion-between-user-and-himanshu).